# How to make Distinct Column in a View while on Inner Join - SQL

Tags: sql

Column names in each view or function must be unique. Column name `'ur_id'` in view or function `'v_userStatus'` is specified more than once

```
CREATE VIEW v_userStatus AS
    select *
    from tbl_user inner join
         tbl_userrole
          on tbl_user.u_user_role_id = tbl_userrole.ur_id
    where tbl_user.u_isDelete = 0 and tbl_userrole.ur_id = 2;
```

Comment: can you provide the table structure for both tables from which view is created. from the error message it seem `ur_id` is present in both the tables.

Comment: I have both ur_id in table tbl_user and table tbl_user_role

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `select *`.  You can take all the columns from `tbl_user` and then additional ones from user role:

```
CREATE VIEW v_userStatus AS
     select u.*, ur.?, ur.?
     from tbl_user u inner join
          tbl_userrole ur
          on u.u_user_role_id = ur.ur_id
     where u.u_isDelete = 0 and ur.ur_id = 2;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Gordon Linoff. It is the answer.